# Embedding websites in html

Tags: html, embed

I am trying to figure out the way this website : totallyscience.co embeds their games into the site because I am trying to make a website and I tried directly embedding a website and it isn't the same.

I tried < embed src="example.com" > and it is definitely not the same as the website listed above.

Comment: It seems you may be over your skis, and need a 101 in HTML before you start attempting to build something out  ..  Start with reading about what [<embed>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) does .. Actually sitting down and *reading* before performing a task is going to help you immensely.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here AND what totallyscience.co uses is an `iframe` tag

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" title="Embedding another webpage"></iframe>
```

You can style and position it as you need.

**tip** : Try to use secure links (`https`) in iframe. You can use a `https` link in a page loaded over `http` but not the other way.

For further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP